# first loop breaks the second loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to display data via a loop using ACF[advance custom fields, Option Page] in my Footer.

This works on my homepage without any problems. But if i navigate to sub-pages it breaks , meaning it would show maybe only the `page_links` row or on another page only the `images_footer` row.

It confuses me because **home page works perfectly normal** and shows all footer data from below.

Also i looked if there is any conflict in the custom-fields names towards the sub-pages custom-fields names and the footer but i dont find any.

Another thing if i would remove the first loop the second one works this is only on some pages, so weird.

If i keep the first while loop ,delete the second while loop, and navigate to other pages,the first while loop show on some pages and some not, how is this even possible.

*I have done some var_dumps(); after both if statements, but obviously the dump does not. So it doesnt even pick up the row -> ('page_links', 'option') or in some cases ('images_footer', 'option').

Any helpful tips would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="col-lg-8">

  <div class="links">

  <?php      
   if( have_rows('page_links', 'option') ): 
   while( have_rows('page_links', 'option') ): the_row();         
  ?>
  <p><a href="<?php the_sub_field('footer_link');   ?>"><?php the_sub_field('footer_link_name'); ?></a></p>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>   
  </div>

  <div class="foot-images">
  <?php
   if( have_rows('images_footer', 'option') ): 
   while( have_rows('images_footer', 'option') ): the_row();
  ?>                              

  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="<?php the_sub_field('logo_image');   ?>" alt=""></div>    
  <?php endwhile;endif;  ?> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Following this documentation: [ACF - Get values from an options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/)

Comment: read and apply PSR-2

Comment: thanks @symcbean at least its a helpful tip, its just not really solving my problem, but this got me thinking the problem is within the template page codes where some of the footer data is not displaying, after deleting the template content its displaying all the data of the footer, so ill have a look in my templates something is breaking it in  there not sure what.